# set image in nodes of circle and center of circle

Tags: css, styles

I have written below html to show 7 images below is the html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Rounded Images</h2>

    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This images comes looks like below

[image]

but want this image in circular format so one image is in center and all other images surround it
like circle so tried adding below css

```
.Circle {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: aqua;
    border: 30px solid blue;
}
```

which created circle but how to set image on nodes and center in this circle ?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that this question is answered,i am posting another answer

```css
:root{
  --FullHeight:300px;/* [*] */
  --CircleHeight:75px;/* [*] */
  --totalImages:6;/* [*] */
}
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--FullHeight);
  height: var(--FullHeight);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: solid 5px tomato;
}
.circle-container > * {

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: calc(0px - (var(--CircleHeight) / 2));
  width: var(--CircleHeight);
  height: var(--CircleHeight);
}
.circle-container > *:nth-of-type(1) {
  --cur:1;/* [*] */
  transform: rotate(calc((360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1)))
    translate(calc((var(--FullHeight) - var(--CircleHeight)) / 2)) 
    rotate(calc((0deg - (360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1))));
}
.circle-container > *:nth-of-type(2) {
  --cur:2;/* [*] */
  transform: rotate(calc((360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1)))
    translate(calc((var(--FullHeight) - var(--CircleHeight)) / 2)) 
    rotate(calc((0deg - (360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1))));
}
.circle-container > *:nth-of-type(3) {
  --cur:3;/* [*] */
  transform: rotate(calc((360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1)))
    translate(calc((var(--FullHeight) - var(--CircleHeight)) / 2)) 
    rotate(calc((0deg - (360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1))));
}
.circle-container > *:nth-of-type(4) {
  --cur:4;/* [*] */
  transform: rotate(calc((360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1)))
    translate(calc((var(--FullHeight) - var(--CircleHeight)) / 2)) 
    rotate(calc((0deg - (360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1))));
}
.circle-container > *:nth-of-type(5) {
  --cur:5;/* [*] */
  transform: rotate(calc((360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1)))
    translate(calc((var(--FullHeight) - var(--CircleHeight)) / 2)) 
    rotate(calc((0deg - (360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1))));
}
.circle-container > *:nth-of-type(6) {
  --cur:6;/* [*] */
  transform: rotate(calc((360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1)))
    translate(calc((var(--FullHeight) - var(--CircleHeight)) / 2)) 
    rotate(calc((0deg - (360deg / var(--totalImages)) * (var(--cur) - 1))));
}/* [Duplicate this further more] */
.circle-container > *:nth-last-child {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px) rotate(0deg);
}


.circle-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Rounded Images</h2>

<ul class='circle-container'>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
  <li><img src='https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/631/816/original/vector-blue-square-grid-mosaic-background-creative-design-templates.jpg'></li>
</ul>
```

here commented lines like `/* [*] */` means you have to edit

## Features

- Fully *variablized*
- **Aligned in circle** ***properly***

#### [A pen](https://codepen.io/neptotech/pen/NWwOKxd)